# Передача значения из OpenDialog в TextBox на общей форме

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые. На форме лежат TextBox и Button. Элементы созданы программно. При нажатии на Button вызывается OpenDialog. Пытаюсь выполнить передачу значения OpenDialog в TextBox, но похоже путаюсь в видимости компонентов формы. При указании в процедуре кнопки Click - this или форма недоступна. Подскажите пожалуйста, как передать значение результата выбора OpenDialog в TextBox на форме.

```
public void databaseoptionItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form optionForm = new Form(); 
    TextBox databasePathTextBox = new TextBox();
    databasePathTextBox.Parent = optionForm;
    optionForm.Controls.Add(databasePathTextBox);
    Button databasePathButton = new Button();
    databasePathButton.Parent = optionForm;
    databasePathButton.Click += new EventHandler(databasePathButton_Click);
    optionForm.Show();
}

public void databasePathButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    OpenFileDialog databaseOpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (databaseOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        optionForm.    ?(не вижу ни формы ни объектов)
    }
}
```

Comment: сделайте `optionForm` не локальной переменной метода, а приватным полем класса формы

Comment: Большое спасибо, Bulson. Действительно, при создании приватного поля класса а потом присвоения ему создаваемого элемента появилась видимость его в пределах формы. Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Вынес поле TextBox в приватное поле класса (сделал видимым для всего класса).

```
private TextBox _databasePathTextBox;

public void databaseoptionItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form optionForm = new Form(); 
        _databasePathTextBox = new TextBox();
        databasePathTextBox.Parent = optionForm;
        optionForm.Controls.Add(databasePathTextBox);
        Button databasePathButton = new Button();
        databasePathButton.Parent = optionForm;
        databasePathButton.Click += new EventHandler(databasePathButton_Click);
        optionForm.Show();
    }

public void databasePathButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        OpenFileDialog databaseOpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (databaseOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
           _databasePathTextBox.Text = optionForm.FileName;
        }
     }
```

Comment: спасибо, Мурад, все получилось.